# VS 2017 SPATemplate module resolution

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a simple Angular2 app in VS2017 using the [SPATemplate](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/).

It was going well until I created a data model and service module to invoke Web API services.

I factored out the data model into policy.ts, the service is in policy.service.ts.

policy.ts works as expected, but the pre-renderer can't find policy.service.[Here's an image that shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnHPe.png)

I confirmed that Visual Studio is loading a recent version nodejs (6.10.0), but I don't know how to proceed to find the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Since the file containing the error is under a subdirectory, do you need to use ../ to back up one level?

Comment: Show the code and the error in the question instead of linking an image

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments and suggestions. As I was adding the details you requested I found the answer.

The file name was misspelled: *policy.sevice.ts* instead of *policy.service.ts*.

Stack Exchange saves the day again.

bojackey